# Create log record based on user sign in activity C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, logging

I want to record the  DateTime and the result of the login(success or fail) when someone tries to sign in into my tool either the sign-in is successful or failed. I want to display the record on my Main Page of my tool. Is there any way to do that? Or is it impossible?

this is the table for log

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogInfo] (

[LogID]     VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,

[DateTime]  DATETIME2 (7) NULL,

[Exception] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LogID] ASC)
);
```

this is the code for login

```
SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM UserSignUpTable Where Username = '" + textBoxusername.Text + 
               "' AND UserPassword = '" + Encrypt(textBoxpwd.Text) +"'", 
                connection);

connection.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapt.Fill(ds);
connection.Close();
int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

if (count == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Success", "USBlocker", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    this.Hide();

    MainPage2 mainpage = new MainPage2();
    mainpage.Show();
}
else
{
    LoginAttempts = LoginAttempts + 1;
}
if ((LoginAttempts >= 2)) 
{
    //webcam activate

    this.Hide();
    Webcam webcam = new Webcam(); //webcam activate
    webcam.Show();
}
else if ((LoginAttempts == 1))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password", "USBlocker", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    linkLabel1.Visible = true;
    cleartextbox();
}
else if ((LoginAttempts == 2))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password", "USBlocker", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    cleartextbox();
}
else
{
    cleartextbox();
}
```

Comment: Please add some more information about your table structure and other things so that someone can help you.

Comment: What infrastructure do you have? What code is ready so far? Abstractly, I can say use Log4Net with SQL Appender, and only write log statements that you want to capture in DB

Comment: Yes... create a database table where you can story this logs... and insert the rows in to the table when user's login is successful failure...

Comment: I already add the sql for the table. I just dont know on how to record the success or failure during the login

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava i dont code it yet because I want to know first either it is possible or not

Comment: Can you share the code which verifies if the user's login is successful or not?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya done

Comment: @asa Some well-intentioned advice: You are mixing up database access, logic (login attempts) and UI concerns in one method, please do yourself a favor and read on separation of concerns. Furthermore (and this is *more severe*) you are concatening strings for SQL statements. **Do. Not. Ever. Do. This!** You are opening doors (widely) for SQL injections. Use parameterized SQL statements instead.